# How do I make procedrual spider legs move only when the opposite legs are grounded in Unity with one script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, scripting

Im trying to make a procedrualy animated spider(In unity) and I have got all the code worked out inside only one script but right now all of the four legs move at the same time, and I want them only to move when the opposite legs are grounded as showed in this video:[https://youtu.be/e6Gjhr1IP6w?t=43](https://stackoverflow.com)

My code is down here:
I think the if statements at the bottom is the code that needs to be reworked / changed but I dont know what to do.

For reference, in the bottem if statements the first two if statements are one pair of oppisite legs, and the 2 last if statements are the second pair of oppisite legs.

Help is appriceiated.

Thanks.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ProcedrualAnimationController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform targert1;
    public Transform targert2;
    public Transform targert3;
    public Transform targert4;

    public Transform point1;
    public Transform point2;
    public Transform point3;
    public Transform point4;

    bool isMoveing1;
    bool isMoveing2;
    float lefMoveSpee = 7f;



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit1;
        if (Physics.Raycast(targert1.position + new Vector3(0f, 0.75f, 0f), targert1.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out hit1, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            targert1.position = hit1.point;
            
            Debug.Log("Did Hit");
        }
        RaycastHit hit2;
        if (Physics.Raycast(targert2.position + new Vector3(0f, 0.75f, 0f), targert2.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out hit2, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            targert2.position = hit2.point;

            Debug.Log("Did Hit");
        }
        RaycastHit hit3;
        if (Physics.Raycast(targert3.position + new Vector3(0f, 0.75f, 0f), targert3.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out hit3, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            targert3.position = hit3.point;

            Debug.Log("Did Hit");
        }
        RaycastHit hit4;
        if (Physics.Raycast(targert4.position + new Vector3(0f, 0.75f, 0f), targert4.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out hit4, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            targert4.position = hit4.point;
            Debug.Log("Did Hit");
        }






        RaycastHit hitPoint1;
        if (Physics.Raycast(point1.position + new Vector3(0f, 0.75f, 0f), point1.TransformDirection(Vector3.back), out hitPoint1, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            point1.position = hitPoint1.point;
            Debug.Log("Did Hit");
            
        }
        RaycastHit hitPoint2;
        if (Physics.Raycast(point2.position + new Vector3(0f, 0.75f, 0f), point2.TransformDirection(Vector3.back), out hitPoint2, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            point2.position = hitPoint2.point;
            Debug.Log("Did Hit");

        }
        RaycastHit hitPoint3;
        if (Physics.Raycast(point3.position + new Vector3(0f, 0.75f, 0f), point3.TransformDirection(Vector3.back), out hitPoint3, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            point3.position = hitPoint3.point;
            Debug.Log("Did Hit");

        }
        RaycastHit hitPoint4;
        if (Physics.Raycast(point4.position + new Vector3(0f, 0.75f, 0f), point4.TransformDirection(Vector3.back), out hitPoint4, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            point4.position = hitPoint4.point;
            Debug.Log("Did Hit");

        }
        float distanceToMovePoint1 = Vector3.Distance(targert1.position, point1.position);
        float distanceToMovePoint2 = Vector3.Distance(targert2.position, point2.position);
        float distanceToMovePoint3 = Vector3.Distance(targert3.position, point3.position);
        float distanceToMovePoint4 = Vector3.Distance(targert4.position, point4.position);

      
        if (distanceToMovePoint1 >= 5 )
        {
          
           targert1.position = point1.position;
        }

        
        if (distanceToMovePoint2 >= 5)
        {
            
            targert2.position = point2.position;
           
        }
        if (distanceToMovePoint3 >= 5)
        {
           
            targert3.position = point3.position;
           

        }
        if (distanceToMovePoint4 >= 5)
        {
            
            targert4.position = point4.position;
            

        }

    }
    
}
```

I have tried using bools, to not move the oppisote leg if the other leg is moving, but it was not successful.

Comment: Not in the spirit of the question I know but save yourself some headaches and use apps designed for animation like Blender, or Unity's own animation system. Quicker than reinventing the wheel and easier to get good looking results :) See https://learn.unity.com/search?k=%5B%22q%3AAnimation%22%5D

Comment: Thanks for your help, I do use blender and Im very good at animating, but If I do animation my creature cannot tranverse complex terrain, it will just "float over" while If I do procedrual animation it will be much more reallistic even though it is alot harder.

Comment: Ah OK. Does something like `if (distanceToMovePoint1 >= 5 && distanceToMovePoint3 < 5)` do what you need?

Comment: That dose not work, did you look at the linked video?